# Ansible: loop/with_list with debug is not working

Tags: ansible

There is something wrong in below small piece of code in ansible. loop/with_list is not printing inside debug. I don't get any output on this block.  If I print the array directly in debug:msg: , I got the output in array format. What i am doing wrong ?

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False
  vars:
    hello:
      - World
      - Asia
      - South America
      - North America
      - Artic
      - Antartic
      - Oceania
      - Europe
      - Africa
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ hello }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "item: {{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ hello }}"
```

Execution:

```
   [17:06:12] debug ...
localhost | SUCCESS | 35ms
{
  - msg: [
           - World
           - Asia
           - South America
           - North America
           - Artic
           - Antartic
           - Oceania
           - Europe
           - Africa
          ]
}
[17:06:12] debug ...
localhost | SUCCESS | 69ms
[17:06:12] system ...
-- Play recap --

$ ansible --version
ansible 2.10.3
```

Comment: What callback plugin do you use? Post `ansible-config dump | grep DEFAULT_STDOUT_CALLBACK`

Answer (score 0):

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False
  vars:
    hello:
      - World
      - Asia
      - South America
      - North America
      - Artic
      - Antartic
      - Oceania
      - Europe
      - Africa
  tasks:
  - name: listing places
    debug:
      msg: "item: {{ item }}"
    with_list: "{{ hello }}"
```

Output

````
TASK [listing places] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=World) => {
    "msg": "item: World"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=Asia) => {
    "msg": "item: Asia"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=South America) => {
    "msg": "item: South America"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=North America) => {
    "msg": "item: North America"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=Artic) => {
    "msg": "item: Artic"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=Antartic) => {
    "msg": "item: Antartic"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=Oceania) => {
    "msg": "item: Oceania"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=Europe) => {
    "msg": "item: Europe"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=Africa) => {
    "msg": "item: Africa"
}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0```
````